# Setting SMB 2.0 as default for mount operations

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, smb

Using a `mount -t cifs -v <address>` returns with `Host is Down` error when connecting to a server running SMB 2.0 (with SMB 1.0 disabled). A workaround is to specify `vers=2.0` to the argument list of `mount`. This works fine if you're mounting via command line and have the ability to specify this argument. But, when using a GUI or some program that calls `mount` on your behalf, this argument is not specified.

Is there a way to make SMB 2.0+ the default for all `mount -t cifs` calls, regardless what calls it? Perhaps in `smb.conf`?

Currently running Arch Linux.

**EDIT:**
Added `min protocol = SMB2` to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and restarted the service. Both `mount` and `smbclient` still require the SMB version to be specified before connecting to the server.

**EDIT2:**
Adding `client min protocol = SMB2` and `client max protocol = SMB3` allows `smbclient` to connect to the server without specifying the version argument. But, `mount` still doesn't respect the newly added lines in `smb.conf`.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the kernel's `cifs` filesystem module does not read `/etc/samba/smb.conf` at all. The CIFS client module that allows mounting of Windows fileshares is completely separate from Samba.

The default protocol level in the `cifs` module was changed to SMB3 in vanilla kernel version 4.13, and a multi-dialect negotiation patch (effectively setting the default to "SMB2.1 or later") was added to the vanilla kernels in September 2017.

I'm pretty sure that the "enterprise" Linux distributions have backported the patch to earlier kernels, but on Arch your only option may be to upgrade to kernel version 4.13 or later.

[Here's a link to the relevant patch in kernel.org Git.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/fs/cifs?h=v4.14.52&id=9764c02fcbad40001fd3f63558d918e4d519bb75) The commit ID might be helpful in tracking the patch in specific kernel versions.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't suppose you know if it's been incorporated in recent Debian kernels do you?

Comment: Debian 9 (the current stable) is at kernel 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (although named `linux-image-4.9.0-6-amd64`) , and unfortunately the only CIFS patch it seems to have is for CVE-2018-1066. Debian testing has kernel 4.16.*, so it already has the patch via upstream.

Answer (score 0):

As part of researching this issue I have written a script that adjusts the CIFS parameters for the `mount` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Force SMB2.0 mount. We prefix the options list because a later explicit
# "vers=..." option overrides the one we add.
########################################################################
#
args=()

# Only consider checking options if we have a CIFS mount
[[ "$*" =~ '-t cifs' ]] && cifs=yes || cifs=

options=
for arg in "$@"
do
    if [[ $next == 'options' ]]
    then
        # Prefix version to options string
        arg="vers=2.0,$arg"
        next=
    fi

    args+=("$arg")

    # CIFS options check
    if [[ $cifs == 'yes' ]]
    then
        [[ $arg == '-o' ]] && next=options
    fi
done

logger -p user.notice -t "${0/*\/}" "intercepted $0 ${args[*]}"
exec "$0.real" "${args[@]}"
```

Install this script as `/bin/mount.sh`. Then run these commands

```
chmod a+x /bin/mount.sh
mv /bin/mount /bin/mount.real && ln -fs mount.sh /bin/mount
```

Uninstall it with

```
test -L /bin/mount && rm -f /bin/mount && mv -f /bin/mount.real /bin/mount
rm -f /bin/mount.sh
```